# msiexec opens popup on Python install

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer

I'm new to Windows and trying to install Python but I don't have admin privileges. I've tried running the script `msiexec /i python-2.7.13.amd64.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:\UserPrograms\python` (and also tried with `/a`) but nothing happens in the terminal. The only feedback I get is the following window pops up:

[image]

but the files aren't installed. It's not really clear what is happening. Is this an error? Is it trying to tell me I typed something wrong?

Comment: It tells you how to use msiexec, which most likely means you made a mistake in the command line. Maybe it does not like TARGETDI**T**?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo on here. Fixed.

Comment: when I do that I get an admin password prompt.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I wonder if it has to do with the admin settings on my computer because I don't even get that

Comment: maybe you're admin and you don't know it :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre haha I wish. Then Python would have worked installing it another way.

Comment: double-clicking does what? asks for password? note that there are some portable installs like anaconda or just (for python 2.7) zip the directory where it's installed and unzip somewhere else: portable version.

Comment: If I click 'OK', the window closes and the script stops silently. Anaconda is fine, but I need Python itself for Node.js. `npm install -G windows-build-tools` tries to install the .msi, but tells me I need to run it from administrative PowerShell